# Remove the default 'no content in table' text for empty javafx table

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I would like to remove or change the default text shown by an empty javafx table from `No content in table` to something more meaningful for the user.

For example in a table showing students, when there are no students to show I want it to say "No students in database" or "Student has no courses" for a courses table. I don't know if this is possible in javafx, either through java code, using scene builder, or by editing the .fxml file in an IDE. So far I have looked at the properties of the tableview in scene builder and I can't see a related property for this text

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You are correct in that the ***[TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html)*** control does not have a `String` setter method that directly manipulates the text shown when the table is empty. What you will want to do instead is use the TableView's [placeholder property](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setPlaceholder(javafx.scene.Node)) which can be set to any object of type ***[Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)***. For example...

```
myTableView.setPlaceholder(new Label("My table is empty message"));
```

Answer (score 53):

You can also do it from *.fxml file, by adding placeholder with empty label.

```
<TableView>
    <placeholder>
        <Label text=""/>
    </placeholder>
    <columns>
        <TableColumn text="Column1"/>
        <TableColumn text="Column2"/>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

Comment: It gives me: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Label is not a valid type.

Comment: @CarlosLópez Even if your problem is quite old now, it can help other : you more likely forget to import the `Label` at the beginning of your FXML file : `<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>`

Comment: @Pagbo indeed this helped me today